# Getting Django Rest Framework to get postdata from specific post variable

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, vuejs2, axios

I am building a Django application with a Vue.js 2 SPA. This means that everything has to be done using AJAX calls. In my case, these are handled with axios.

To make things easier, I have found a Form class for ES6 online. This allows me to have a reusable form object that I can easily submit and still handle the `Promise` like if I was doing it directly with axios.
The form class looks like this:

```
import Errors from './Errors';
export default class Form {
    /**
     * Create a new Form instance.
     *
     * @param {object} data
     */
    constructor(data) {
        this.originalData = data;

        for (let field in data) {
            this[field] = data[field];
        }

        this.errors = new Errors();
    }


    /**
     * Fetch all relevant data for the form.
     */
    data() {
        let data = {};

        for (let property in this.originalData) {
            data[property] = this[property];
        }

        return {data};
    }


    /**
     * Reset the form fields.
     */
    reset() {
        for (let field in this.originalData) {
            this[field] = '';
        }

        this.errors.clear();
    }


    /**
     * Send a POST request to the given URL.
     * .
     * @param {string} url
     */
    post(url) {
        return this.submit('post', url);
    }


    /**
     * Send a PUT request to the given URL.
     * .
     * @param {string} url
     */
    put(url) {
        return this.submit('put', url);
    }


    /**
     * Send a PATCH request to the given URL.
     * .
     * @param {string} url
     */
    patch(url) {
        return this.submit('patch', url);
    }


    /**
     * Send a DELETE request to the given URL.
     * .
     * @param {string} url
     */
    delete(url) {
        return this.submit('delete', url);
    }


    /**
     * Submit the form.
     *
     * @param {string} requestType
     * @param {string} url
     */
    submit(requestType, url) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            axios[requestType](url, this.data())
                .then(response => {
                    this.onSuccess(response.data);

                    resolve(response.data);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    this.onFail(error.response.data);

                    reject(error.response.data);
                });
        });
    }


    /**
     * Handle a successful form submission.
     *
     * @param {object} data
     */
    onSuccess(data) {
        console.log(data);
        this.reset();
    }


    /**
     * Handle a failed form submission.
     *
     * @param {object} errors
     */
    onFail(errors) {
        this.errors.record(errors);
    }
}
```

The part that is currently giving me some issues is that, when I submit the data to Django REST Framework, I get all the handling of the code by using the ModelSerializer, but I cannot seem to find an easy way to tell it that the `POST` data is structured a little different from what it is expecting.
This is a sample request data:

```
{"data":{"name":"b-0123","windfarm":2,"longtitude":"234","latitude":"345","ip_address":"10.0.0.123"}}
```

I know that the solution is either to let Django know that it should get the `POST` data for the model, from `request.POST['data']` or to get the ES6 Form class to pass the raw fields instead of sending everything as a data object.
The part I do not know is how to get either of these to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that it was quite simple to get this working.
I just had to change this:

```
/**
 * Fetch all relevant data for the form.
 */
data() {
    let data = {};

    for (let property in this.originalData) {
        data[property] = this[property];
    }

    return {data};
}
```

into this:

```
/**
 * Fetch all relevant data for the form.
 */
data() {
    let data = {};

    for (let property in this.originalData) {
        data[property] = this[property];
    }

    return data;
}
```

This returned me the data array instead of an object with the data array